# Drag & Drop only going one folder deep in Finder on Monterey MBP 2021

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, trackpad

On a new MacBook Pro 2021 14" I'm expecting that when I drag and hold a file over a folder, then it opens that folder so that I can see the next hierarchy level. However, currently the file just stays over that folder, but doesn't open it.

I tried the Accessibility settings as well as the Trackpad settings, but with no luck so far. Using an Apple Bluetooth Mouse also didn't solve the problem.

I've noticed that the folders on my Finder Desktop, where this isn't working, are not showing these "disclosure triangles" as others are, where this is working

[image: folder icons on Desktop]
[image: folder icons Subfolders, showing these triangles]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just to confirm that I am aware of this post, but the steps there haven't solved the issue for me: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388693/drag-and-drop-only-going-one-folder-deep-in-finder

Comment: The problem was sorted by, in the Finder, disabling "Group by...". This problem is solved.